# Adding material to gameobject in Unity is making it invisible

Tags: unity-game-engine

I’m making a 2d game and I don’t have any assets yet so I’m just using squares and materials so I can tell things apart. Everything was working out ok until I put a material on the player sprite. I simply made a new material, changed its color, and put it on the square I’m using for the player, and the player just turned invisible. I didn’t change anything with the alpha channel while making the material, and I tried deleting the material and making a new one but nothing worked. I also tried messing with the lighting in my scene, but being fairly new to Unity, I couldn’t figure it out. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Edit: I also just reset the material so it should just be a plain white but it still isn’t visible

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the material itself. Any chance it's a single-sided material and just not visible from the direction you're looking in? Does it show up if you look from the other side?

Comment: No, I just put it in 3d mode to test that and I can’t see it from any angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a check in the shader of the material. If you're using sprites, instead of the Standard shader, change it to Default (inside the Sprites tab).

[image]